# Duplicate class issue when Firebase BOM(firebae-pref) used with protobuf in android app

Tags: android, firebase, protocol-buffers, proto

I am using **proto** in my android app. Now I am trying to use firebase **BOM(26.6.0)** with **firebase-pref**.

When I am running build, getting duplicate class issue.
build.gradle -

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.6.0')
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing"
    //implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-perf")
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1"
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        // You still need protoc like in the non-Android case
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.7.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            // The codegen for lite comes as a separate artifact
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                // In most cases you don't need the full Java output
                // if you use the lite output.
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                javalite { }
            }
        }
    }
}

sourceSets{
    main.java.srcDirs += "${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/javalite"
}
```

Tried commenting
**implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1"**
and using
**implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0'**

It also didn't work. Can any suggest any work around so that I can use updated firebase as well as keep proto usage intact.

Answer (score 0):

becase protobuf-lite:3.0.1 and protobuf-javalite:3.14.0 all have a class named com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite. but the class code not compatible each other. some difference as below:

in javalite:3.14.0 AbstractMessageLite have an interface

```
protected interface InternalOneOfEnum {
    int getNumber();
}
```

but AbstractMessageLite in protobuf-lite:3.0.1 do not have the interface.

so the only way you can solve the problem is to delete a protobuf。
add exclude like  `exclude group: 'com.*.*'` not work for this problem.